# What libraries are available to record a user browsing your website for usability testing?

Tags: javascript, usability, usability-testing

I remember seeing a JavaScript library a long time ago that offered the ability to record where users clicked and moved their mouse on your website, in order to do usability testing. I can't seem to find it anymore.

Are there any libraries out there that do something like this?

What I'm looking for is something like http://clixpy.com/, where you can include some javascript on a page and get videos of what users do.

Answer (score 2):

There's a big list here: http://www.usefulusability.com/24-usability-testing-tools/

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware of [Crazy Egg](https://www.crazyegg.com/) that allows to build heatmaps and track clicks:

> CrazyEgg’s Confetti and Heatmap features are simple and affordable heat mapping tools that allow you to visually understand user behavior.
>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [crazyegg.com](http://www.crazyegg.com/images/new/confetti.jpg))</sub>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [crazyegg.com](http://www.crazyegg.com/images/new/heatmap.jpg))</sub>

Crazy Egg is a commercial service.

Comment: I've used crazyegg before and can highly recommend them ... great for A-B testing too!

Answer (score 1):

We use Clicktale and it is quite OK. With it you can understand users a bit better. But, I strongly recommend doing usability tests or depth interviews rather. You can do it with your friends them pretending to be the real users if getting them users is tricky. I assure you, it is SOOOO much better than any javascript. And don't forget to record them while they click - it is priceless.

You might want to consider UserView from TechSmith. I don't have any experience with it, but from the promo material it seems like professional out-of-the box solution for many implementations and it could save you quite some dev work.

But I didin't anwser your question :D I also remember stumbling upon an opensource jscript lib ... don't remember the name though, but I've found this on Google:
http://piwik.org/docs/javascript-tracking/

Answer (score 1):

http://pure.rednoize.com/movelogger/ is a free one!

Answer (score 0):

http://userfly.com/ is another easy one (paid I think).